# Grunt Copy task does not copy parent folder's file into the correct folder

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

My current tree is :

```
root
├── web-server.js
├── app
     ├── grunt.js
     ├── dist
```

My grunt file is :

```
    copy: {
    commons: {
        src: ['../web-server.js'],
        dest: 'dist/'
    }

},
```

When i execute my script from app folder my web-server.js is not copied to "dist" folder but to "app" folder.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `cwd` option. Thus, the folder structure will be preserved.

Change your Grunt task as follows:

```
copy: {
    commons: {
        cwd : '../',
        src  : ['web-server.js'],
        dest : 'dist/',
        expand: true
    }    
}
```